# Get unreplied message from MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table in mysql which is not properly structured. It was developed by a previous developer. Table structure in below:-

```
id (primary_key)
from_user_id (sender)
post_id (thread_id)
to_user_id (receiver)
Message (text_content)
datetime (mysql_timestamp)
```

lets say our inter user id (from_user_id) exist in a predefined array i.e. (4,182,193).

So i want to get only those rows on which last reply was made by user that is not exist in the above array.

I have made a query but that is returning only a single row.

Can you all please help me on that?

My query is:-

```
SELECT * 
from table 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT MAX(id) 
  FROM table 
  where from_user_id not in (4,182,193)
)
GROUP BY post_id;
```

Comment: SELECT MAX(id) will return only one ID that is maximum among all your IDs. So, your query is indirectly becoming like this 
SELECT * 
from table 
WHERE id IN 123
GROUP BY post_id;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the last id for any posts and then use the resulting ids as filters:

```
select *
from table t1
where from_user_id not in (4,182,193)
  and id in
(
select max(t2.id)
from table t2
group by t2.post_id
)
```

Comment: Thank You so much @Lajos Arpad. It solved the problem. You saved my day. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ShariqueAnwer you are welcome. If the answer was a solution indeed, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

for get all the id not in your array you should select all the ids not only the max  and use `where id not in` .. too.

for a comparision you need  a column name

```
    SELECT * 
    from table 
    WHERE id IN (
      SELECT id
      FROM table 
      where from_user_id where id  not in (4,182,193)
    )
```